# gaps between divs with padding 0 and border 0

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout which I got from the web I discovered that the divs  do not touch each other. As in top of lower div does not touch bottom of div above it.. It does when the border is on but the background shows through when borders are removed.. 
Header does not touch nav with borders gone...?
Here is code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>A two column layout from the internet</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles2.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"><h1>Document heading</h1></div>
     <div id ="nav">
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#">option 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">option 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">option 3 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#">option 4 </a></li>
           <li><a href="#">option 5 </a></li>
       </ul>
     </div><!--navigation -->
     <div id ="main">
       <h2>column 1 #Main  float:left; </h2>
       <p> This is column one so we can imagine the text ,pictures etc in here </P>
      <p>Note the sum of the widths must add up to the width of the wrapper
          Note:adding a border to the main div moves the `enter code here`sidebar div down..
          so an increase of the wrapper by 2px fixes this so we may conclude that 
          the size of a div exludes borders.
       </p>
     </div><!-- main-->
     <div id="sidebar">
       <h2>column 2 #sidebar float:right</h2>
       <p> here stuff for column two... .....</p>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">link 3 </a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div id="footer">
       <p>footer</p>
       <p> Note without the clear both property added to the footer it does not sit below the content but underneath the  
        the floated content. floating an element takes it out of the document flow.. prior to the floats the footer does as expected sit
        below the sidebars.. left and right.. 
       </p>
         </div>
       <div><!-- end wrapper often used to centre the site-->
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

The float property should fix it. Just float the divs left (or wherever).

```
#header {
    float:left;
}
#nav {
    float:left;
}
```